# Make my website browser selective

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was wondering if there is any way, a script, a PHP code, or anything, or even if it is possible to only allow specific browsers to display my site.

If a "wrong" browser tries to visit, then show a "noscript" message.

```
<noscript> Eww!! Site Allergic to Mozilla, Try Google Chrome instead. </noscript>
```

Comment: you can implement that in server side by checking which client is trying to connect to you and ignore the request for specific browser.

Comment: How do i do that??...thx

Comment: Check my snippent once this will really help you to resolve your issue

Comment: @KretsTopsey don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you. so that others will know it worked

Answer (score 0):

use regex to check browser.

That is

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
/chrome/i.test(ua) ; //will return true for chrome and do this for all
```

Then make a `function` which check the `userAgent` with all browsers you need and `return true` if match else `return false`.

Call the function on `window.onload` and if `false`, just `alert` a message and use `window.location.href=newpath` to redirect to somewhere else.

Comment: Caan someone help me complete this?...i really don't know what i am doing here

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var FF = !(window.mozInnerScreenX == null);
    if(FF) {
            alert("try another browser");
            window.location.href = "elsewhere.html"
        // is firefox 
    } else { 
        // not firefox 
    }
```

For chrome

```
$.browser.chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 

if(!$.browser.chrome){

        alert("try chrome browser");
        window.location.href = "elsewhere.html"
    }
```

**OR**

```
var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);

if(!isChrome){window.location.href = "elsewhere.html"}
```

Comment: Thx for this, but sadly only works on mozilla...tried with IE, mozilla, Chrome & Epic...only rejects mozilla

Comment: this is just for mozilla ... do you want to check other browsers too?/

Comment: Yes i want to check all browsers...only chrome browser should be alowed.

Comment: then check for chrome and redirect if it's not chrome... see updated answer

Comment: Yeah...this is exactly what i was looking for, the third option i mean...thx for your help guys...you all are awesome

Answer (score 0):

### Try This script for check browser

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    /* Get browser */
    $.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
 if($.browser.chrome) {
   alert('Crome browser detected.');
   $.browser.msie = false;
   $.browser.mozilla = false;
    } else if ($.browser.mozilla) {
       alert('Try crome insted of mozilla.');
       $.browser.chrome = false;
     $.browser.mozilla = false;
    } else if ($.browser.msie) {
       alert('Try crome..');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not working at all...tested wit IE, Mozilla & Chrome